# iOS Image Assets sizes

Tags: ios, image, retina-display, retina

In XCode 6, in the asset catalog (xcassets) we are now given the options for an image set of 1x, 2x, and 3x

We know 1x is 320 x 480.

And 3x needs to be 1242 x 2208

But 2x has several options:  640 x 960, 640 x 1136, or 750 x 1334

Do I just go with the largest one (750 x 1334), and it will scale it down for iPhone 5?

It seems that, just like the Launch Image and Icon size assets, that there should be more options for a general image asset.